# Project with path ':expo-modules-core' could not be found in expo module

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I have created an expo module using `yarn create expo-module` according to the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/modules/overview/)

When I open `android` folder of the module in Android Studio and run gradle sync, it produces an error:
`Project with path ':expo-modules-core' could not be found in root project 'android'`

Gradle script uses `project(":expo-modules-core")`. `expo-modules-core` is located in `node_modules` directory, but the `expo-module` yarn template doesn't connect to it in any way.

React native plugins on the other hand explicitly specify the location of `com.facebook.react:react-native` inside `node_modules` in gradle:

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url("$rootDir/../../node_modules/react-native/android")
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" // From node_modules
}
```

The same doesn't work for `expo-modules-core` because it doesn't contain maven-metadata

So, the question is how to add a dependency to `expo-modules-core`?

Comment: I have tested this expo-module just add It to the project using packages.json dependency and it works despite the fact that you can't develop your expo-module in android studio. The explanation for this is that, when it builds the project, it copies the expo-module to node_modules where the `expo-modules-core` is located, so it can be referenced in the `expo-module` gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You should link your expo-module to the project using yarn [workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/), after this, you can open the `android` folder of the **workspaces which uses your expo-module** as dependency in android studio. The gradle sync will pass and you will see all the expo modules including yours in the project view.